# Animate width on custom slider

Tags: jquery

I am making a custom jQuery slider. Here is my code:

```
<head>
    <style>
        p { 
            color: red; 
            margin: 5px; 
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        p:hover { 
            background: yellow; 
        }
        img { 
            position: absolute; 
            top: 0px; 
            left: 0px;
        }
        #img1 {
            width: 652px; 
            height: 314px; 
            position: absolute; 
            top: 0px; 
            left: 0px; 
            z-index: 999999;
        }
        #img2 {
            width: 652px;
            height: 314px;
            position: absolute; 
            top: 0px; 
            left: 0px; 
            z-index:99;
        }
        #content {
            height: 350px; 
            width: 500px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="img1" style="background:url(scarf01.jpg);"></div>
        <div id="img2" style="background:url(scarf02.jpg);"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#clickme').click(function() {
                $('#img1').animate({ "width": "0px" }, 1000);  
            });
        });
    </script>

    <div id="clickme">
        Click here
    </div>
</body>
```

When you click on `#clickme` `#img1` slides away to the left. I would like it to slide to the right. I read that I need to float `#img1` right, which I did. I also had to set the position to "relative" for this to work. When I do this the images then become stacked on top of each other.

Any suggestions on how to get around this?

Comment: Please create a fiddler for this and post the url so that we can easily check without having to reimplement ourselves... (fiddler.net)

Comment: That site sounds like a haven for old men with bad habits :p

Comment: jsfiddle.net this is what you want.

Comment: Please take care to format your code correctly. It will make it much easier for you and others to read.

Comment: fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ptW5x/1/

Comment: my code is formatted fine in dreamweaver.... it's only here it looks messy!

Comment: Then fix it here! You need to help the people trying to help you fix your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `left:0px` in to `right:0px;` and add a `position:relative` to your `#content` like:

```
#img1{width:652px; height:314px; position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px; z-index:999999; }
#img2{width:652px; height:314px; position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px; z-index:99;}
#content{height:350px; width:500px; position: relative}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: as mentioned above, the images need to be behind each other as this is a slider

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I have changed my answer. Hope this helps.